# Maven and Spring 3.1.1

Tags: spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Creating a new Spring Template Project in SpringSource Tool Suite it loads Spring Framework **3.0.6** dependencies with the preinstalled Maven. How can I force to load the **3.1.1 version** of Spring Framework?

Comment: I have no experience with `Tool Suite` but usually you change the maven dependencies by editing the `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Template are for Spring 3.0, may Spring Source will add some new for version 3.1.

Meanwhile you can update the spring version in the created `pom.xml` to 3.1.

Replace

```
<properties>
  ...
  <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  ...
<properties>
```

on line 12, by 3.1.1.RELEASE. *May you also need to update the junit version to 4.8 at line 116*

If you need it very often you can create your own custom template. (See [Custom Project Templates in SpringSource Tool Suite](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/24/custom-project-templates-in-springsource-tool-suite/))

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Is it necessary to modify the "settings.xml" file for Maven or not?

Comment: @observer: No, you do not need to modify the `settings.xml` file. You only need to change the `pom.xml` file.